# flow conditional value of state object?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

how can I flow check this file correctly,
This component has a conditional rendering base on the state,
flow said `Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value`

and what if I have a more complicated state structure like {user.owner.name}...
how can I set the type properly?

```js
type User = {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  year: string,
  imdbID: string,
  poster: string,
  trailer: string
};

class AllUser extends React.Component {
  state: {
    repos: Array<?User>,
    repos2: Array<?User>
  };

  handleChange: () => void;
  filterItem: () => void;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      repos: [],
      repos2: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.filterItem = this.filterItem.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.repos.length === 0) {
      fetchPopularRepos("all").then((repos: Array<?User>) => {
        this.setState({
          repos: repos,
          repos2: repos
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.repos.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div>loading</div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.repos.map(repo => <p>{repo.name}</p>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Array<?User>` instead of  `Array<User>`? The `?` means that the array might have null/undefined values, but they you are doing `repo.name` on every entry. This is a valid error given the types you've provided.

Comment: do you mean `repos: ?Array<User>` and by this  flow will smartly choose doing `repo.name` or not ?

Comment: You don't need a questionmark at all. An array is allowed to be empty. What you have now is "an array of either null or a user" essentially, so you said the items in the array can be `null`, but nothing about the code itself implies you'd ever end up with `null` instead of a `User` object.

Comment: 1. I think I understand this part now `repos:  Array<User>` mean repos itself is a Array can be null or a Array of User object. 2. but if it will be `null`, how flow check the User object's properties like `repo.name`, for the following code  `repos.map(repo => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

`repos: Array<?User>` means the `repos` property is "an array of items, where each item can be `null` or `undefined`, or a `User`.

`repos: ?Array<User>` means the `repos` property is "`null` or `undefined`, or an array of items, where each items must be a `User`.

`repos: Array<User>` means the `repos` property is "an array of items, where each items must be a `User`.

Since you are using the first one, with

```
this.state.repos.map(repo => <p>{repo.name}</p>)
```

you Flow recognizes that `repos` will be an array, but your type declaration `Array<?User>` says that `repo` inside the callback could be a `User`, `null` or `undefined`, so since `.name` on a `null` or `undefined` value would throw an exception, Flow is throwing an error. This is the correct behavior given the type.

The two places you assign `repos` are

```
this.state = {
  repos: [],
  repos2: []
};
```

and

```
fetchPopularRepos("all").then((repos: Array<?User>) => {
  this.setState({
    repos: repos,
  });
});
```

So the question for you is, will `fetchPopularRepos` return an array that contains `null` or `undefined` values? It seems strange to me that it would. If an item isn't a user, it just shouldn't be included in the array at all. Including `null` values would just cause confusion.

Given that, the fix here would be to change

```
.then((repos: Array<?User>) => {
```

to

```
.then((repos: Array<User>) => {
```

so you guarantee that the array only contains `User` objects, and then change

```
  state: {
    repos: Array<?User>,
    repos2: Array<?User>
  };
```

to

```
  state: {
    repos: Array<User>,
    repos2: Array<User>
  };
```